# Redux-saga doesn't wait for response from API

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, redux, redux-saga

I use redux-saga and I created a generator `checkUsername` which perform the API call. I though that `const username` will equal to response from API, but I've got `undefined`.

```
function* checkUsername(action) {
  try {
    const username = yield call(Api.checkUsername, action.username);
    yield put({type: actions.USERNAME_CHECK_SUCCEEDED, username});
  } catch (e) {
    yield put({type: actions.USERNAME_CHECK_FAILED, message: e.message});
  }
}
```

Although in my `checkUsername` function, which call API `res` is equal `{"isExist": false}`:

```
 checkUsername(username) {
    fetch(url, {
    'GET',
    headers: {
      'Accept': 'application/json',
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    }
  }).then(response => response.json())
      .then(res => res)
      .catch(error => console.error(error));
 },
```

Why my `const username` is not equal `{"isExist": false}`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your `checkUsername` function you need to return the call to `fetch()`.